# Постраничня навигация

Tags: php

Не выходит сделать постраничную навигацию для песен. Уже кучу сайтов перерыл, везде одно и тоже, у моего друга код работает, у меня почему-то нет.

```
<?
mysql_select_db($db);
mysql_query ("set_client='utf8'");
mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");
mysql_query ("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");
mysql_query ("SET NAMES utf8");
$db="syte";
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")or die;
mysql_select_db($db);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
$num=1;
$result1=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM music2");
$temp=mysql_fetch_array($result1);
$posts=$temp[0];
$total=(($posts-1)/$num)+1;
if (empty($page) or $page<0) $page=1;
if($page>$total) $page=$total;
$start=$page*$num-$num;
$query=mysql_query("select * from `music2` limit $start, $num");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
     if ($row['Ссылка'] != "" && file_exists("music/" . $row['Ссылка'])){
            $muz = 'music/' . $row['Ссылка']; 
            echo '<div id="spisok_pesen"><ul><li><h3>' . $row['Название'] . '</h3><audio src=' . $muz . ' controls></audio></li></ul></div>';

}}
if ($page != 1){ $pstr_prev = '<li><a class="pstr-prev" href="nav.php?page='.($page - 1).'">&lt;</a></li>';}
if ($page != $total) $pstr_next = '<li><a class="pstr-next" href="nav.php?page='.($page + 1).'">&gt;</a></li>';


// Формируем ссылки со страницами
if($page - 5 > 0) $page5left = '<li><a href="nav.php?page='.($page - 5).'">'.($page - 5).'</a></li>';
if($page - 4 > 0) $page4left = '<li><a href="nav.php?page='.($page - 4).'">'.($page - 4).'</a></li>';
if($page - 3 > 0) $page3left = '<li><a href="nav.php?page='.($page - 3).'">'.($page - 3).'</a></li>';
if($page - 2 > 0) $page2left = '<li><a href="nav.php?page='.($page - 2).'">'.($page - 2).'</a></li>';
if($page - 1 > 0) $page1left = '<li><a href="nav.php?page='.($page - 1).'">'.($page - 1).'</a></li>';

if($page + 5 <= $total) $page5right = '<li><a href="nav.php?page='.($page + 5).'">'.($page + 5).'</a></li>';
if($page + 4 <= $total) $page4right = '<li><a href="nav.php?page='.($page + 4).'">'.($page + 4).'</a></li>';
if($page + 3 <= $total) $page3right = '<li><a href="nav.php?page='.($page + 3).'">'.($page + 3).'</a></li>';
if($page + 2 <= $total) $page2right = '<li><a href="nav.php?page='.($page + 2).'">'.($page + 2).'</a></li>';
if($page + 1 <= $total) $page1right = '<li><a href="nav.php?page='.($page + 1).'">'.($page + 1).'</a></li>';


if ($page+5 < $total){
    $strtotal = '<li><p>...</p></li><li><a href="nav.php?page='.$total.'">'.$total.'</a></li>';}
else{    
$strtotal = ""; }
if ($total > 1){   
echo '<ul>    ';
    echo $pstr_prev.$page5left.$page4left.$page3left.$page2left.$page1left
    ."<li><a 'href='nav.php?page=".$page."'>".$page."</a></li>".$page1right.$page2right.$page3right.$page4right.$page5right.$strtotal.$pstr_next;
    echo '
    </ul>
    </div>
    ';

   }
?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Переменные не инициализированы, т.к. на первой странице отсутствуют предыдущие страницы. Самый простой вариант инициализировать их пустой строкой по типу:

```
$page1left='';
```

И так сделать с каждой. Такой вариант подойдёт для временной отладки, но не для нормального использования.

Comment: Ну а почему у моего друга всё без этого работает ? Не знаете ? И как лучше поступить, чтоб нормально использовать ?

Comment: Думаю если вы выберете 6ую страницу, то всё заработает, как планировалось. На мой взгляд нужны проверки, если есть такие переменные, то только тогда выводить их.

Comment: Нет, оно выводит всё те же 2 песни. Какую бы страницу не выбрал.

Comment: Инициализировал все переменные - работает. Спасибо большое.

Comment: Перенёс в свой код - не работает. У меня выводится инфо в зависимости от нажатой кнопки. Если выводить всю инфу, то оно работает.

Comment: $start вроде принимает одно  и тоже значение, наверное нужно  считывать GET запросом номер текущей страницы.

Comment: А, оно на get тоже ругается.

Comment: А как вы его пишете, как он ругается?

Comment: $page = (int)$_GET['page']; Пишет, что неизвестный индекс page

Comment: а в адресе строка вида /nav.php?page=34  или что-то другое? Опять же нужно придумать кучу условий для проверки существует ли что-либо

Comment: Page нету. Просто music.php(это страница, где у меня через кнопку выводится)

Comment: тогда откуда ему брать значение page?

Comment: А как тогда сделать ? Если оно не выводит это значение

Comment: Мне кажется вам нужно разобраться сначала с какими-то азами, не знаю почему у вашего друга всё работает. Для решения проблемы с page нужно условие типо if($_GET['page']) $page = (int)$_GET['page']; else $page = 1; Советую задуматься стоит ли так бегло костылями запускать чтобы что-то работало или всё таки стоит нормально сесть и научиться делать сайты на PHP с вывода "Hello World" до соц. сети с поддержкой миллионов пользователей.

Comment: Спасибо, пойду работать на стройку.